# VBA Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Tags: vba, input

Seguinte, estou apanhando do VBA para navegar em uma página web (pode ser com o Internet Explorer)

Basicamente encontrei alguns códigos com o Método `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. Porém não consigo fazer o input nos campos usando o ID do objeto para conseguir logar na pagina.

Preciso logar na pagina usando **id="username"** e **id="passwd"**, clicar no botão **id=".salve"**, entrar no site (o que seria outra pagina obviamente) e lá dentro do site clicar em outro botão.

Sei o nome dos objetos porque olhei o código fonte do site, mas não sei se isso tudo é possível, ou se tenho que armazenar o local atual em uma variável. Isso é possível? Como faço?

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é possível.

```
' Cria um novo objecto do IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

' Indica ao IE que deve navegar para a página
IE.Navigate "http://aminhapagina.com" 
IE.Visible = True 

' Loop de espera até o IE carregar a página
Do while IE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

' Preenche os campos necessários
IE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = "username" 
IE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "password"

' Invoca a função clique do botão de salvar
IE.Document.All.Item(".salve").Click
```

Desta forma, após clicar no botão e se for bem sucedido e navegar para a página seguinte, basta aplicar a mesma lógica, procurar o botão que necessita com o `IE.Document.All.Item(...)` e invocar a função `Click`.

Answer (score 1):

conseguiu resolver seu problema?

caso não veja se isso ajuda!

Olhe no código fonte da página e veja se tem alguma tag chamada de (Frame ou Frameset), se tiver ai esta o problema, pelo fato de você manipular o IE, ele manipula por tela ou seja pela tag  que são sub divididas por div e por essas Frame, para conseguir manipular os eventos que estão contidos nesses frames você deve somente informar ao VBA onde e qual frame o objeto esta!

```
IE.Document.frames(0).Document.all("username").innertext = "username"
IE.Document.frames(0).Document.all("senha").innertext = "senha"
```

caso não tenha funcionado me avise!